# Why [ebp-8] is the location of the first local variable in visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

When I program in visual studio 2019, I input the following code and I compile it in debug mode and do some disassembly. I discover that the variable "c" is located in address ebp-8(in myfunction). However, I read from books that "the first local variable should appear in address ebp-4". Is there something with visual studio or with debug mode?

int myfunction(int a, int b)
{
013017B0 55                   push        ebp
013017B1 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp
013017B3 81 EC D8 00 00 00    sub         esp,0D8h
013017B9 53                   push        ebx
013017BA 56                   push        esi
013017BB 57                   push        edi
013017BC 8D BD 28 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp+FFFFFF28h]
013017C2 B9 36 00 00 00       mov         ecx,36h
013017C7 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh
013017CC F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]
013017CE B9 08 C0 30 01       mov         ecx,130C008h
013017D3 E8 3F FA FF FF       call        01301217

```
                   //Nonsense above.


int c = a + b;
```

013017D8 8B 45 08             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  //a

013017DB 03 45 0C             add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  //b

013017DE 89 45 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax   //Why it is not [ebp-4]?
}

Comment: I also discover that the second varible "i" is located at [ebp-14], which i think should be [ebp-12].

Comment: Please update you question instead of extending it in comments.

Comment: The appearance of 0xcccccccc is the cue, tells you that you are looking at the Debug build with the /RTC option turned on.  Which initializes local variables with a wonky value so you can find variable initialization bugs.  And surrounds variables with this magic value so you can find buffer overflow bugs.  The latter feature moves variables from their normal location.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that Visual Studio is leaving 8 bytes between local variables in **debug** mode, but in **release** mode it is working normal as expected.